# How to configure rsyslog inside docker image centos 8

Tags: docker, rsyslog, centos8

I'm building a docker image based on `centos` that contains a `postfix` configuration. However, it's not working correctly, so I'm trying to debug it. I want to enable rsyslog, so I can see the logging.

However, the default `rsyslog.conf` does not log anything. What is the proper way to set-up local logging for rsyslog in a centos8 docker image?

Answer (score 1):

This mini config seems to work

```
module(
    load="imuxsock"
    SysSock.Use="on"
)

#### RULES ####

mail.* /var/log/mail

*.* /var/log/messages
```